# typescript setState from Context is possibly undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, type-assertion

Typescript complains that my setReposlist is undefined. I am confused because I think have previously typed using this interface:

```
export interface ReposContextInterface {
    reposList: {},
    setReposList?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<reposList>>
}
export interface SearchPageContextInterface{
    searchRepos: ReposContextInterface
}
export const SearchPageContext = createContext({} as SearchPageContextInterface);
```

and I define the context on my app.tsx:

```
 <SearchPageContext.Provider value={{searchRepos: {reposList, setReposList}}}>
```

but when I use the context on my react component like this:

```
const SearchPage = useContext(SearchPageContext);
const {searchRepos} = SearchPage;
useEffect(()=>{
  
    const getRepos = async (username: string) =>{
      const repos = await axios.get(`https://endpoint/${username}/repos`);
      if(repos) {
        const {data} = repos;
        const temp:any = {};
        temp[username] = data;
        setReposList({...reposList, ...temp});
      } else {
        setReposList({...reposList});
      }
    };
  getRepos(username);
    
  },[]);
```

it gives me this error message:
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
const setReposList: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction> | undefined

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest entirely removing the optionality in the context type and using a dummy object as an initial value. Something like this:

```
interface ReposContextInterface {
    reposList: {},
    setReposList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<reposList>>
}

export const SearchPageContext = createContext<ReposContextInterface>({reposList: {}, setReposList: () => null})
```

If you wish to keep the optionality of the `setReposList`, you can use optional chaining:

```
setReposList?.({...reposList});
```